# Flow of vector fields and inequality

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, exponential-function, lie-algebras

Let $X,Y$ be smooth vector fields of a manifold $M$ (equipped with a metric) and $q\in M$.

We denote by $e^{tX}q$ the point of $M$ such that we integrate the ODE
$$
\dot x = X(x)
$$
during time $t$ and starting from $q$.

Is it true that
$$
|| e^{tX}e^{sY}q||\le ||e^{tX+sY}q|| ?
$$

---

Applying BCH formula, we get:

$$
e^{tX}e^{sY}q = e^{tX+sY+1/2st[X,Y]+\ldots}
$$

but I am trying to find a counterexample to reject the inequality.
I mean if $X$,$Y$ are such that $X\cdot Y\ge 0$ and $[X,Y]\le 0$, the terms
in $[X,Y]$ will bring the final point closer to the initial point.

I tried on $\mathbb{R}$, with $X(x)=1$ and $Y(x)=x$ so $[X,Y]=-1$ but in fact I get the equality ...

Source : http://sci-hub.tw/10.1137/0316047

[image: BCH]

Comment: How are you defining $e^{tX+sY}$? The most sensible definition I can see is $e^{tX+sY}=e^{tX}e^{sY}$, but that would make your question trivial...

Comment: Indeed I don't know the definition of $exp(tX+sY)$. But these terms appear in the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formulae (see pciture)